# Determine whether some expression contains a symbol doing nothing?

Tags: symbolic, expression-test, free-form-input, expression-form

I have expression like this:

```
expr = xuyz;
```

then

```
Head[expr] = xuyz
```

But I wanted the product of four factors, so it should have been written as
`x*u*y*z` or `x u y z`, because Mathematica understands multiplication of four single-character variables in these two ways only.

So I need to detect whether or not an expression is written in the right way. By "right" I mean all variables should are required to be single-character, all factors to be such variables or function thereof, and all terms to be products of such factors .

I have tried with:

```
FreeQ[expr, Times].
```

But it doesn't help, because I can have the situation

```
xu*y
```

which is not right for me, because `xu` and `y` are are the factors and I want `x`, `u` and `y` to be the factors.

So is there any way to detect this problem?

Answer (score 5):

```
f1 = Max@StringLength[SymbolName /@ Variables@#] == 1 &;

f1 /@ {xu*y, 3 x + w z^2}
```

> {False, True}

Answer (score 3):

This returns `True` because of `xu` and/or `gh`

```
Max[StringLength[ToString /@ DeleteCases[Level[xu*y/gh, {-1}], _?NumericQ]]] > 1
```

> True

Comment: I think you should write Max[...] > 1 for getting True because of xu and gh.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[testVars]

testVars::usage = 
  "testVars[expr, allowedVars] returns variables appearing in expr that \
are not in the list allowedVars.";

testVars[expr_, allowedVars_?VectorQ] :=
 Complement[Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]], allowedVars]

vars = {x, y, z};

testVars[xyx, vars]

(*  {xyx}  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thoroughly tested the following function, but at least it might be a good starting point for you to solve your problem.

```
singleCharVarsQ[expr_] := 
  AllTrue[
    StringLength /@ SymbolName /@ 
      Cases[expr, Except[_?NumericQ, _?AtomQ], ∞], # == 1 &]

singleCharVarsQ[x y z + x Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - Cos[xy]]
```

> `False`

```
singleCharVarsQ[x y z + x Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - Cos[x y]]
```

> `True`